# Flask: How to create one or more time-consuming process in Flask, celery or python multiprocessing module

Tags: python, flask, multiprocessing, celery

Now i'd like to use Flask to implement a Backend service that provide some RESTful-APIs for frontend to query the data in local database. And all data in local database are produced&analyzed from another remote database.

I think have to create a asynchronous process constantly to get original data from the remote DB in which new data constantly generated, and analysis&transforming these data, and save to local DB(convenient for REST query).

Moreover while the process of analysis some special data have to be pushed to Frontend via web-socket.

For the above functionality how can i create an async time-consuming process in Flask to do the data-analysis, use the flask-celery or multiprocessing module or any other implementation?